# What is the cleanest way to redefine math-mode font commands such as \mathrm and \mathit to use a different font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

**What is the cleanest way to redefine math-mode font commands such as `\mathrm` and `\mathit`?**

I would like everything else to be unaffected; for example, perhaps I enjoy working with `mathptmx` and I want to keep its `\mathnormal`, but I want to change `\mathrm` and `mathit` to use a different font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}


\begin{document}

Some text.

Some formula: \(abc = de/f \quad[\mathrm{var}, \mathit{val}]\)

\(\mathnormal{abc = de/f}\)

var, \textit{val}

\(\mathrm{var}, \mathit{val}\)

% Bitstream Charter
{\fontfamily{bch}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont  var,
 \fontfamily{bch}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{it}\selectfont val}

% Linux Biolinum
{\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont  var,
 \fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{it}\selectfont val}

% Linux Libertine
{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-OsF}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont  var,
 \fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-OsF}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{it}\selectfont val}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using Charter for `\mathrm` when the main font is Times is a typographic nonsense.

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure I feel that strongly about it :-) but sometimes a bit of variety serves illustrative purposes, to give examples for the question.

Comment: @egreg (`bch` is way better than some of the other choices that'd look outrageous in math mode.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just redefine the macros `\mathrm` and `\mathit` to use a different font: the interface is

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
```

You can also supplement the font for a different math version: say also

```
\SetMathAlphabet{bold}{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
```

for defining the font to be used in a `\boldmath` (or `\mathversion{bold}`) context.

An example follows. But beware that using Charter for `\mathrm` and `\mathit` is a typographical nonsense. Here's the visual proof of my claim.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{OT1}{bch}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{OT1}{bch}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

Some text.

Some formula: \(abc = de/f \quad[\mathrm{var}, \mathit{val}]\)

Some formula: \(\mathit{abc}=\mathit{de}/\mathit{f}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\DeclareMathAlphabet` one can define a substitute that won't eat up math families:

```
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \newcommand{\mathcharter}[1][\encodingdefault]{%
   \text{\usefont{#1}{bch}{m}{n}#2}%
 }
```

and use it as

```
\mathcharter{abc}
```

or even

```
\mathcharter[T1]{l'Hôpital}
```

Comment: What function does the `OT1` serve? (I know it's about the "encoding", but practically what does that mean here? Somewhere in the preamble I have the line `\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}`, with `T3` included for `tipa`. Are there alternatives to `OT1`?)

Comment: @LoverofStructure Not really; with `\mathrm` you should only use ASCII characters.

Comment: Normally yes; do I need to modify the preamble to also include `OT1` for my loading of `fontenc`?

Comment: @LoverofStructure No, `OT1` is predefined.

Comment: Slightly different question: *New* declarations with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` can eat up new math alphabet slots. Is there a good one-time way of doing this in a document? What's the difference to just using `\fontfamily`?

Comment: @LoverofStructure Using `\fontfamily` doesn't work in math mode.

Comment: Is there a simple one-off way (not something clumsy such as `\fontfamily` inside an `\mbox`) for math mode?

Comment: @LoverofStructure `\text{\fontfamily{whatever}\selectfont...}`

Comment: Oh, `\text`, right. And let's make that `\text{\fontfamily{...}\fontseries{...}\fontshape{...}\selectfont ...}`.

Comment: Upon experimentation it's actually not clear to me when math families are eaten up; issuance of `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}` in some document of mine ate up no math families (even though I specified a new font), but additional issuance of `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}` just after that ate up two of them.

Comment: @LoverofStructure The math families are allocated only when expressly requested in a math formula for the first time.

Comment: But then, the compiler throws a `LaTeX Error: Command '\mathit' already defined.`.  How to keep it from throwing that error every compilation?

Comment: @Alex The code in my answer doesn't produce the error.

Comment: @egreg Apparently, I declared it after including the package the contains the `\mathit`command.  After switching the order of declaration, it now works without error.